# Form keyup event starts to rise only after i minimise the form C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, events, keyup

this is my code

```
private void Player_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.Focus(); 
        this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Player_KeyUp);
    }
    private void Player_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode + " " + e.KeyValue);
    }
```

after i minimise the form the message box starts to show up

Comment: No repro.  `this.Focus()` makes no sense in the Load event, the form isn't visible yet.  It should be unnecessary to call that.

Comment: i have tried to remove it and remove `KeyPreview` but same behavior happens

Comment: If you don't use the MessageBox.Show() overload that takes an *owner* argument then it goes hunting for an owner window itself.  It picks the active window.  Apparently your "Player" window isn't the active one so some odds that the message box appears *underneath* your window.  You can't see it until you minimize the window.  Exactly how you got a KeyDown event without the window being active is very hard to guess, something is very screwy in the rest of the program.